# Set function repeating values from dictionary

Tags: python, set

I have a dictionary and I want to loop through the values without having repeating values so I am using set() but it still has all the values.

Here is the code

```
favourite_languages = {
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phil': 'pyhon'
    }

print("The following languages have beeen mentioned:")
for language in set(favourite_languages.values()):
    print(language.title())
```

The result I get is:

```
The following languages have been mentioned:
C 
Python
Ruby 
Python (I don't want this one)
```

The result I want is:

```
The following languages have been mentioned:
C
Python
Ruby
```

Also every time I run the code the order changes.(Don't know if that has something to do with the problem)

I am using the latest version of Python(Python 3.9) and I am using Sublime Text to run the code.

Comment: could just be a typo `s/pyhon/python`

Comment: That can't happen with `set()`.

Comment: You must be misreading the output.

Comment: after correcting the typo, you don't get the second python, I ran it

Comment: python != pyhon

Comment: Another thing: you're doing case conversion with `title()` after you make the set. There could be elements that are the same except for case, they would both be put in the set.

Comment: as @Barmar said, Python != python

Answer (score 1):

You should convert all the values to title case *before* putting them into the set. Otherwise, values that are the same except for different character case will both be put in the set.

```
for language in set(lang.title() for lang in favourite_languages.values()):
    print(language)
```

And as mentioned in comments, you also have a typo in your input data: `pyhon`. But you don't have that in your sample output, so it's not clear which is the copying error.

Comment: wow I just noticed the typo

Comment: Wow, it was the first comment someone made.